# Why ms excel is very slow over VPN connection?

Tags: excel, vpn

I am not able to modify the excel sheet when i am connected to VPN Client.
If I disconnet the VPN, excel is working properly.
If I connected to VPN and trying to modify excel, excel is going in not responding mode.

Please give me some suggestion, how to overcome from this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are running Excel on your local machine and are just connected to the VPN for some other reason (not using RDP)
.
In this case what comes to mind is that perhaps office is trying to access the internet (update check, help etc) and the connection through VPN is slower than normal (or even blocked on the port office's trying to access.

Have you tested other office apps such as Word, Powerpoint? Do they all run slower when you are on the VPN?